# Set Time Zone for all Windows Servers on a Domain (2008 R2)

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2008-r2

Is there a way I can set the time zone for all machines on my domain (perhaps using a group policy?).  All the Windows machines are Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command tzutil.exe is available on Windows 7 / 2008

```
TZUTIL </? | /g | /s TimeZoneID[_dstoff] | /l>

Parameters:
    /? Displays usage information.

    /g Displays the current time zone ID.

    /s TimeZoneID[_dstoff]
       Sets the current time zone using the specified time zone ID.
       The _dstoff suffix disables Daylight Saving Time adjustments
       for the time zone (where applicable).

    /l Lists all valid time zone IDs and display names. The output will
       be:
           <display name>
           <time zone ID>

Examples:
    TZUTIL /g
    TZUTIL /s "Pacific Standard Time"
    TZUTIL /s "Pacific Standard Time_dstoff"
```

To set to UTC use a command like `TZUTIL /s "UTC"`.

Comment: A real improvement over the old way of doing things, and if you set it as a startup-script in a GPO it'll go everywhere.

Comment: +1 - It's nice not to have to hack the registry anymore.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of approaches that might work, export a "correct" registry fragment and import it via a script, which is a bit hacky but doable. Or there's an article [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/deploymentguys/archive/2009/06/07/setting-the-time-zone-using-windows-powershell.aspx) that discusses doing it with a powershell script, with some examples.